# Easy way to transform XPath with contains to equals check?

Tags: xpath

Is there an easy way to transform an XPath query (as string), like:

```
my/x/path[contains(sub/path, 'text')]
```

to an XPath query which uses equals instead of `contains`? Such that I can easily use the same query, one time with `contains` and another time with `equals`? Unfortunately there is no "equals" function in XPath...

Comment: There is no technically sound way to modify an XPath string the way you want to. There are only dirty ways (i.e. search-and-replace with regular expressions) that work in a strict and narrow sub-set of possible XPath expressions. Depends on the strings you have if they can work for you or not.

Comment: Instead of transforming XPath expressions, you could still use `contains` and filter the result for just the elements that match the text perfectly. Is this an option?

Comment: kjhughes's answer might satisfy you. Otherwise, you could add more context to your question (the environment you use XPath in, e.g. Java, XSLT, Python; the reason why you need those two versions of path expressions, perhaps show an XML sample).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might differentiate between the two options via a flag:

```
my/x/path[ ($wantContains and contains(sub/path, 'text'))
            or 
           (not($wantContains) and sub/path = 'text')
         ]
```

Comment: Found nothing better, so I have settled with that solution, thanks.